# how to get which is selected when Checkbox and Radio button added programmatically in android

Tags: android, android-checkbox, android-radiobutton

```
private void parseProductOptionData(JSONObject response){
    try {
        boolean success = response.getBoolean("success");
        if(success){
            rlProductOption.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            //Get All the Categories
            JSONArray data = response.getJSONArray("data");
            if(data.length()!=0){
                rlProductOptionQuantityTxt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                for(int i= 0;i<data.length();i++){
                    //First Get Type
                    JSONObject optionQuantity = data.getJSONObject(i);
                    Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: option quantity"+optionQuantity);


                    //Create a Layout
                    llMainLayout = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
                    llMainLayout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                    llMainLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.border_details);
                    llMainLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
                    llMainLayout.setPadding(10,0,10,5);
                    llProductOptionsSheet.addView(llMainLayout);



                    tvOptionTitleText= new TextView(getActivity());
                    tvOptionTitleText.setId(Integer.valueOf("1"+i));
                    tvOptionTitleText.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                    tvOptionTitleText.setTypeface(Typeface.SERIF);
                    llMainLayout.addView(tvOptionTitleText);
                    tvOptionTitleText.setText(optionQuantity.getString("title"));

                    if(optionQuantity.getString("min_selection").equals("1") && optionQuantity.getString("max_selection").equals("1")){
                        RadioGroup maxAndMin = new RadioGroup(getActivity());
                        maxAndMin.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
                        maxAndMin.clearCheck();

                        //maxAndMin.setId(Integer.valueOf("1"));
                        maxAndMin.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                        Log.d(TAG, "Option length1 "+optionQuantity.getJSONArray("options").length());
                        for (int btnCount =0;btnCount<optionQuantity.getJSONArray("options").length();btnCount++){
                            RadioButton rdbtn = new RadioButton(getActivity());
                            //rdbtn.setId(i);
                            //if (btnCount==0)
                            rdbtn.setText(optionQuantity.getJSONArray("options").getJSONObject(btnCount).getString("name")+" ("+optionQuantity.getJSONArray("options").getJSONObject(btnCount).getString("price")+")");
                            maxAndMin.addView(rdbtn);
                        }
                        llMainLayout.addView(maxAndMin);
                    }else if(optionQuantity.getString("min_selection").equals("0") && optionQuantity.getString("max_selection").equals("1")){
                        RadioGroup maxAndMin = new RadioGroup(getActivity());
                        maxAndMin.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
                        maxAndMin.clearCheck();
                        //maxAndMin.setId(Integer.valueOf("1"));
                        maxAndMin.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                        Log.d(TAG, "Option length1 "+optionQuantity.getJSONArray("options").length());
                        for (int btnCount =0;btnCount<optionQuantity.getJSONArray("options").length();btnCount++){
                            RadioButton rdbtn = new RadioButton(getActivity());
                            //rdbtn.setId(i);
                            rdbtn.setText(optionQuantity.getJSONArray("options").getJSONObject(btnCount).getString("name")+" ("+optionQuantity.getJSONArray("options").getJSONObject(btnCount).getString("price")+")");
                            maxAndMin.addView(rdbtn);
                        }
                        llMainLayout.addView(maxAndMin);
                    }else{
                        Log.d(TAG, "Option length2 "+optionQuantity.getJSONArray("options").length());
                        for (int btnCount =0;btnCount<optionQuantity.getJSONArray("options").length();btnCount++){
                            Log.d(TAG, "Option data fetch "+optionQuantity.getJSONArray("options").getJSONObject(btnCount).getString("name"));
                            CheckBox cbMaxOption = new CheckBox(getActivity());
                            cbMaxOption.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                            cbMaxOption.setText(optionQuantity.getJSONArray("options").getJSONObject(btnCount).getString("name")+" ("+optionQuantity.getJSONArray("options").getJSONObject(btnCount).getString("price")+")");
                            llMainLayout.addView(cbMaxOption);
                        }


                    }
                }

            }else{
                Log.d(TAG, "No product option ");
                rlProductOptionQuantityTxt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            btnAddToCart = new Button(getActivity());
            btnAddToCart.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            btnAddToCart.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.color_btn_login));
            btnAddToCart.setText(getActivity().getResources().getString(R.string.add_to_cart));
            btnAddToCart.setTypeface(Typeface.SERIF);
            btnAddToCart.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            llProductOptionsSheet.addView(btnAddToCart);
            btnAddToCart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    tvOptionTitleText.setError("please fill all the text");
                }
            });

        }else{
            rlProductOption.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),response.getString("message"),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Sorry try Later!!!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        rlProductOption.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
```

This is my code in which i have add radio button and checkbox according to json data.So when i click on a button "btnAddToCart" then i want to know all the selected checkbox and radio button.beacuse i have to store all the selected data in my session.

Answer (score 0):

Declare a global variable like:

int rlProductOptionQuantityTxt =0;// for default case

Use Switch case,

@Override
    public void onClick(View view)
    {
       switch (view.getId())

{

case R.id.yourRadioButton:

```
           rlProductOptionQuantityTxt =1;
```

}

}

and then you can directly use the value of your global variable.

SetGet.setProductOptionQuantityTxt(rlProductOptionQuantityTxt );

Answer (score 0):

```
int radioButtonID = radioButtonGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
View radioButton = radioButtonGroup.findViewById(radioButtonID);
int idx = radioButtonGroup.indexOfChild(radioButton);
```